# JS files breaking in same document "TypeError: $(...) is null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with a friend's site. So the gist is, she has all these Javascript files in the same HTML document, taking half of the files out lets you use the corresponding applications while adding the entire Javascript files cause issues and most of her applications break. Pretty much things start to work once I take out her Change Calculator, Vending Machine, and Dice roller.

I'm thinking there are either a) too many javascript files or b) some of these files are in conflict with one another.

I'll paste the HTML code below...

I could paste the JS but I will not as there is so much. Any thoughts would be helpful.

**Firefox gives a debug error:**

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
<anonymous>
 main.min.js:1
 main.min.js:1:39412

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
<anonymous>
 main.js:7
 main.js:7:1

TypeError: this.outerNode.getElementsByTagName is not a function
ProgressBar()
 progressbar_library.js:10
<anonymous>
 progressbar.js:41
jsLib.dom.ready()
 jslib_dom_ready.js:18
jsLib.dom.readyInit/<()
 jslib_dom_ready.js:31
 progressbar_library.js:10:22
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Created February 8, 2016-->
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="Name of Copyright Holder" />
    <meta name="dcterms.dateCopyrighted" content="2015" />
    <meta name="description" content="A short description of the page" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>     
    <meta name="keywords" content=/>
    <meta name="description" content= />

    <link href="css/js-page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
    <!--makes folders operate-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/folders/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/folders/uilang.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/folders/main.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/folders/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/folders/mobile.js"></script>
    <!-- table of powers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/powers/table_of_powers.js"></script>
    <!-- Progress Bar -->  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bar/jslib_dom_ready.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bar/jslib_event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bar/progressbar_library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bar/progressbar.js"></script>
    <!-- 3D Carousel -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/jslib_css.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/jslib_event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/jslib_event_mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/jslib_event_keyboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/carousel_library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/carousel.js"></script>
    <!-- Change Calculator --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calc/calculateChange.js"></script>
    <!-- Change Calculator --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calc/calculateChange.js"></script>
    <!-- vending machine -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vending/vending_library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vending/vending.js"></script>
    <!-- dice roller -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dice/dice_library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dice/dice.js"></script>
     <!--Date updated, courtesy of Gregory Carroll--> 
<script>
 function makeArray() {
          for (i = 0; i < makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
            this[i] = makeArray.arguments[i];
        }

        function getFullYear(d) {
          var y = d.getYear();
          if (y < 1000) {
            y += 1900
          };
          return y;
        }

        var days = new makeArray("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
        var months = new makeArray("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

        function format_time(t) {
            var Day = t.getDay();
            var Date = t.getDate();
            var Month = t.getMonth();
            var Year = getFullYear(t);
            timeString = "";
            timeString += days[Day];
            timeString += ", ";
            timeString += months[Month];
            timeString += " ";
            timeString += Date;
            timeString += ", ";
            timeString += Year;
            return timeString;
          }


        m = new Date(document.lastModified);
        d = new Date();
        $(function() {
          $('.timestamp').html(format_time(m))
        });
</script>

    <!--favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/js_logo.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

    <title>England's Showcase Website: JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="js">
        <header>
            <img id="logo" src="assets/js.png" alt="JavaScript logo"/>          
        </header>






        <p></p>
            <div class="folderOpenClose" onclick="toggleAllFolders();">OPEN/CLOSE ALL FOLDERS</div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);">Table of Powers</div>
                <div id="folder0" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 25, 2016 -->
                    <div id="table_powers">
                        <p id="power-integer">Enter an integer from 1 to 10 in the text box and click the
                        Powers button to see the square and cube of the numbers from one
                        to the value entered.</p>
                        <p id="table">
                            <input type="text" name="maxbase" id="maxbase" />
                            <input type="button" value="Powers" name="showpowers" id="showpowers" />
                        </p>
                        <textarea name="powers" id="powers" rows="12" cols="24"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder1&#39;);">Progress Bar</div>
                <div id="folder1" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 25, 2016 -->
                    <div id="progress_bar">
                        <div id="progressbar" class="outerbar">
                            <div id="innerbar">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="center">-->
                            <input type="button" value="Go to 100%" id="toggleBar" />
                        <!--</div>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder2&#39;);">3D Carousel</div>
                <div id="folder2" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 25, 2016 -->
                    <div id="carousel">
                        <div id="fishing_pics">
                            <img style="position: absolute; left: 553px; top: 263px; z-index: 7;" src="assets/javascript/casting1.jpg" alt="Casting 1" id="casting1_01" height="159" width="106"/>
                            <img style="position: absolute; left: 346px; top: 333px; z-index: 105;" src="assets/javascript/casting2.jpg" alt="Casting 2" id="casting2_01" height="181" width="271"/>
                            <img style="position: absolute; left: 436px; top: 360px; z-index: 197;" src="assets/javascript/catchrelease.jpg" alt="Catch and Release" id="catch-release_1" height="281" width="375"/>
                            <img style="position: absolute; left: 672px; top: 345px; z-index: 154;" src="assets/javascript/fish.jpg" alt="Fish" id="fish_01" height="245" width="327"/>
                            <img style="position: absolute; left: 727px; top: 306px; z-index: 37;" src="assets/javascript/lures.jpg" alt="Lures" id="lures_01" height="129" width="194"/>
                        </div>
                        <ul id="carousel-list">
                            <li>Use CTRL-Left and CTRL-Right or move the mouse over the
                            carousel to spin the carousel.</li>
                            <li>Use CTRL-Up and CTRL-Down to tilt the carousel view.</li>
                            <li>Press ESC to pause/resume the carousel.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder3&#39;);">Change Calculator</div>
                <div id="folder3" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 24, 2016 -->
                    <div id="coins">            
                        <label class="coinLabel">Enter number of cents (0-99):</label>
                        <input type="text" id="cents"  class="disabled" />
                        <input type="button" value="Calculate" name="figure" id="figure"  />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <label class="coinLabel">Quarters:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="quarters" class="disabled" disabled="disabled" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="coinLabel">Dimes:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="dimes" class="disabled" disabled="disabled" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="coinLabel">Nickels:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nickels" class="disabled" disabled="disabled" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="coinLabel">Pennies:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="pennies" class="disabled" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder4&#39;);">Slide Show</div>
                <div id="folder4" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 25, 2016 -->
                    <div id="slideshow">
                        <div id="slide-intructions" >
                            <table class="tableSlides">
                                <caption>KEYBOARD CONTROLS</caption>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Key</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Spacebar</td>
                                    <td>Toggle Pause/Play</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Left-arrow</td>
                                    <td>Previous Image When Paused</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Right-arrow</td>
                                    <td>Next Image When Paused</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Esc</td>
                                    <td>Resets Slide Show</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="tableSlides" >
                                <caption>MOUSE CONTROLS</caption>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Mouse</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Shift+Click</td>
                                    <td>Toggle Pause/Play</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Click</td>
                                    <td>Next Image When Paused</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Right-click</td>
                                    <td>Previous Image When Paused</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <p id="note"><b>NOTE:</b> Right click doesn't work in <i>Opera</i>.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pic-slides">
                            <ul class="center" id="imageList">
                                <li><a href="assets/javascript/casting1.jpg" title="Casting 1" id="casting1_02">Casting 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="assets/javascript/casting2.jpg" title="Casting 2" id="casging2_02">Casting 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="assets/javascript/catchrelease.jpg" title="Catch and Release" id="catch-release_02">Catch and Release</a></li>
                                <li><a href="assets/javascript/fish.jpg" title="Fish" id="fish_02">Fish</a></li>
                                <li><a href="assets/javascript/lures.jpg" title="Lures" id="lures_02">Lures</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="center">
                                <button id="btnPrevious" disabled="disabled">
                                    <img src="assets/javascript/prev.gif" alt="Previous Image" />
                                </button>
                                <button id="btnPlay">
                                    <img src="assets/javascript/pause.gif" alt="Play or Pause" id="imgPlayPause" />
                                </button>
                                <input type="button" id="btnSpeed" value="Fast" />
                                <button id="btnNext" disabled="disabled">
                                    <img src="assets/javascript/next.gif" alt="Next Image" />
                                </button>
                            </p>
                            <p class="center"><span id="caption">Casting 1</span></p>
                            <p class="center">
                                <img src="assets/javascript/casting1.jpg" alt="Casting 1" id="image" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder5&#39;);">Vending Machine</div>
                <div id="folder5" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 25, 2016 -->
                    <div id="vending-machine">
                        <div class="vending-machine">
                            <input type="button" value="Dollar" id="dollar" />
                            <input type="button" value="Quarter" id="quarter" />
                            <input type="button" value="Dime" id="dime" />
                            <input type="button" value="Nickel" id="nickel" />
                            <input type="button" value="Refund" id="refund" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="vending-machine">
                            $ <input type="text" id="deposit" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="vending-machine">
                            <input type="button" value="Coke" id="coke" />
                            <input type="button" value="Pepsi" id="pepsi" />
                            <input type="button" value="Mountain Dew" id="dew" />
                            <input type="button" value="Dr. Pepper" id="pepper" />
                            <input type="button" value="Root Beer" id="rootbeer" />
                            <input type="button" value="Water" id="water" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="vending-machine">
                            <span id="all-products">All products $0.75</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder6&#39;);">Dice Roller</div>
                <div id="folder6" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 24, 2016 -->
                    <div id="roller">
                        <label id="die1">Die 1:</label>
                        <input class="die" name="die1_results" id="die1_results" type="text"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label id="die2">Die 2:</label>
                        <input class="die" name="die2_results" id="die2_results" type="text"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label id="message">Message:</label>
                        <input id="dice-message" name="roll_button" type="text"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="button" id="roll_button" value="Roll the Dice" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
            <div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder7&#39;);">Area &amp; Perimeter Calculator</div>
                <div id="folder7" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Added February 24, 2016 -->
                    <div id="area_perimeter">
                        <label class="calculator" for="length">Length:</label>
                        <input class="lenth" type="text" id="length" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="calculator" for="width">Width:</label>
                        <input class="lenth" type="text" id="width" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="calculator" for="area">Area:</label>
                        <input class="lenth" type="text" id="area" disabled="disabled" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="calculator" for="perimeter">Perimeter:</label>
                        <input class="lenth" type="text" id="perimeter" disabled="disabled" />
                        <br />      
                        <br />      
                        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="calculate" />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
        <br/>

        <footer>
            <div class="timestamp-wrap">
                <p id="copyright">
                    Copyright &#169;
                <!-- function for year change  -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        now=new Date();
                        year=now.getFullYear(); 
                    </script> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(year);
                    </script>
                    | All Rights Reserved
                    <br/>
                      UPDATED: <span class="timestamp"></span>
                </p>
            </div>

                Back to <a href="historyIndex.html" title="Return to History and Presnetation Homepage" target="_blank"><i>History &amp; Presentation</i> Homepage</a>
                <br/>
                Back to <a href="index.html" title="Return Home" target="_blank">Main Page</a>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too many jQueries: 1: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` 2: `script type="text/javascript" src="js/folders/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: For sure remove the second jQuery

Comment: we need to see  main.min.js. It's saying you have a null variable on lines 1  and 7. Un-minify your code, run and get a proper stack trace or noone can help

Comment: Yeah I figured that, I also get a similar error after removing the one in /folders/

Will do!

Comment: Jeez! Just make one js file and use jQuery's [`$.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Answer (score 0):

There already seem to be 2 versions of jquery loaded, which might cause conflicts. Also, different libraries might use the `$` variable. If this is the case, to avoid conflict, try using [jQuery in noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode before using the jQuery $ variable, like so :

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```